# What causes lodash debouncer "TypeError: Expected a function" error?

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I'm attempting to use lodash's debouncer method in a react function component.  When I attempt to create the debouncer-wrapped callback, I receive

> TypeError: Expected a function

at the point of the useCallback statement.  I've attempted to work through three or four examples, but none of them work within my existing app.  The latest attempt I'm working through is [here](https://dev.to/reflexgravity/use-lodash-debouce-inside-a-functional-component-in-react-4g5j).

```
  const [userQuery, setUserQuery] = useState("")
  const [deb, setDeb] = useState("");

  const updateQuery = () => {
      setDeb(userQuery)
      };
      
  //const delayedQuery = useCallback(debounce(updateQuery, 500), []);
  //const delayedQuery = useCallback(debounce(updateQuery, 500), [userQuery]);

  const delayedQuery = useCallback(() => debounce(updateQuery, 500), [userQuery]);
  
  const onChange = e => {
     setUserQuery(e.target.value);

  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
     delayedQuery();
  
     // Cancel the debounce on useEffect cleanup.
     return delayedQuery.cancel;
  }, [userQuery, delayedQuery]);
```

The code functions overall without the debounce wrapper and related return in the useEffect (without any debouncing, of course).

Other variations have are shown in comments, but all lead to the same error.

I'm at a level of modestly comfortable with React so have a lot of gaps in my deeper understanding that could be the problem.

**Edit**
The message reads to me as though debounce isn't recognized as being a function.  I receive no indications of issues attempting to import debounce using either `import { debounce } from 'lodash/has';` or `import { debounce } from 'lodash/fp';`

Error results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was importing the wrong lodash function.  Specifically, I was originally importing:

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash/fp';
```

which (from my partial understanding) is a wrapper that better applies to functional programming techniques.

In this case, what I needed was to import:

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `delayedQuery()` you return the debounced function, and not the result of calling the debounced function. Since `debounce` returns a debounced function with the cancel method, and `useCallback` accepts a function, define `delayedQuery` like this:

```
const delayedQuery = useCallback(debounce(updateQuery, 500), []);
```

Comment: I thought about this approach as well. Why I discarded it: Does the `useCallback` actually return its first parameter (if conditions are unchanged) or does it wrap it inside another method anyway? According to its docs, I assume the latter one (`useMemo(() => fn, deps)`), which means the `cancel` method is still not available on `delayedQuery`. Therefore, maybe a 2-phase approach would be better, to have both the `debounce` from your suggestion and the `cancel` incorporating mine? What do you think?

Comment: `cancel` exists on the returned function. Feel free to try it.

Comment: Okay, I was just not sure about it.

Comment: I think I have not been that deep into `useMemo` and `useCallback` before as right now. Thank you, @Ori Drori!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the mentioned `TypeError` was thrown during the `useEffect`, since you have not provided any Stack Trace.

**Edit** thanks to the comment and suggestion by @Ori Drori:
Change the `delayedQuery` to the following:

```
const delayedQuery = useCallback(debounce(updateQuery, 500), []);
```

This way, you will have a memoized value of your debounced method, which will be a callback anyway, with the available `cancel` property.

---

*Previous Answer (just for reference):*

Then you can try changing your `useEffect` to the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const query = delayedQuery();
  query();
  
  // Cancel the denounce on useEffect cleanup
  return query.cancel;
}, [userQuery, delayedQuery]);
```

---

**Explanation**

You can have a look at the different types of your methods and callbacks. I‘ll start at the beginning:

1. [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) simply takes any method and returns a new method, which will simply invoke the provided method. It will match the signature of the provided method.
2. The provided callback, in turn, is a simple arrow function, which returns a [`debounce`d](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/debounce/) method.
3. The [`debounce`d](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/debounce/) method, according to the lodash docs, can either be called immediately, `cancel`ed or `flush`ed.

This leads us to the following in your `useEffect`:

- `delayedQuery` is a callback.
- You call `delayedQuery()`, where the hook invokes the arrow function.
- The arrow function invokes the `debounce` and returns its value — the debounced `updateQuery`!
- *BUT*: at this point, your query has not yet been invoked! Moreover, since *only the return type of your callback* is a debounced function, there is no property `delayedQuery.cancel`.
- And because `delayedQuery.cancel == undefined`, you get the mentioned `TypeError`.

Comment: The Explanation is **great**, but the solution won't be a debounced behavior, since a new function would be called each time. Debounce works when calling the same debounced function every time.

Comment: You‘re actually right, however, the question was about what causes the `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks for all the background.  I fear the challenge may lie more in the debounce function not being recognized.